# Submit form to specific overloaded Action Method

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a form as follows:

```
<form asp-action="Cards" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" id="IdPageNum" name="pageNum" />
</form>
```

And I have two overloaded Action methods as follows:

```
    [Route("/cards/")]
    public IActionResult Cards(int pageNum)
    {
        /*something something*/
        return View();
    }

    [Route("/cards/{*cardname}")]
    public IActionResult Cards()
    {
        /*something something*/
        return View();

    }
```

When I am in a page like "/cards/{*cardname}" I have a kind of back button. On click, I submit the form as follows:

```
document.getElementById("IdPageNum").value = pageToSend;
document.forms[1].submit();
```

When I used it, what I want it to do is to navigate back to the previous "/cards/" page with the parameters I send, calling the first overloaded method which has (int pageNum) argument. But instead, it calls the second overloaded method, which has no arguments, and it kind of refreshes the page. How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: Try adding an `action` attribute to your form and set it to `"/cards"`. Currently the form gets submitted to the same location that your form is on.

Comment: @coderboy I have following error message:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'action' attribute for <form>. A <form> with a specified 'action' must not have attributes starting with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action', 'asp-controller', 'asp-fragment', 'asp-area', 'asp-route', 'asp-page' or 'asp-page-handler' attribute.

Comment: Hi @zibidigonzales, from your code, tag helper will generate `action="/cards"`, if you want to submit the form, you need send request by js like:`"/cards?pageNum="+pageToSend`.

Comment: Hi again, @Rena. Thank you. That's how I solved it for now. Is there any other way to make it without changing the URL? My supervisor don't want to see those "pageNum="+pageToSend." part in the URL. I hid it in JS but it appears for a split second when the page is opened.

Comment: @coderboy i tried your advice with asp-action attribute but it did the same thing again.